# How can I connect to wireless network using a wireless dongle in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: internet

i have dual operating system xp and ubuntu 11.10 and trying to connet internet by using HSDPA 3GPP Release5 Micromax Dongle but it is working in windows xp not in ubuntu.I am unable to connect internet even i have done my edit connection and all the setting using aircel network but unable to connect internet.plz give me a sugession how could i do manually.

How can I connect to wireless network using a wireless dongle in Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try booting on a ubuntu 12.04 cd and test your dongle, there many fixes and improvement concerning hardware recognition, if it works you will just have to update your system to 12.04.

regards